# Problem inconsistent grouping images in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, caption, group

Using Word 365 to produce a newsletter.  Much of it entails inserting images with attached captions explaining the image.  To speed things up wrote some code to import the edited image from my desktop, (always called 001.jpg), formatting the image and attaching a caption and grouping the caption with the image.  The inconsistent problem is that the code groups them correctly in a new blank document but when the document has a few images the grouping does not work.

When you are inserting 50+ images in a document it's a pain having to manually group the caption.

Here is my code, any suggestions would be appreciated

```vb
Sub ImportImages()
'Imports an image from my desktop called 001.jpg which should be a cropped image ready for moving / manipulating in the docucument

'Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+S

Dim i As Integer

With ActiveDocument
    
    .Shapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
       "C:\Users\Roger Currier\OneDrive - *********\Desktop\001.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        
    With .Shapes.Item(.Shapes.Count)
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = CentimetersToPoints(6.26)
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTight
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    'find the last shape (picture)inserted have to use the highest count
    i = .Shapes.Count
        'check if the current shape is a picture
        If .Shapes.Item(i).Type = msoPicture Then
            .Shapes.Item(i).Line.Weight = 1
            'change the border style to single
            .Shapes.Item(i).Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            'select the picture
            .Shapes.Item(i).Select
            'assign a caption to it
            Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", Title:="", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=True
            'Inserting a caption increases the number of shapes
            .Shapes.Item(i + 1).Line.Weight = 1
            .Shapes.Item(i + 1).Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            .Shapes.Range(Array(.Shapes.Item(i).Name, .Shapes.Item(i + 1).Name)).Group
            'select the group to allow for movement
            .Shapes.Item(.Shapes.Count).Select
            
        End If

End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: See https://www.codevba.com/Word/Shapes/AddPicture.htm#:~:text=Returns%20a%20Shape%20object%20that%20represents%20the%20picture  Since `Shapes.AddPicture` returns the just-added shape, you can skip the `Shapes.Item(.Shapes.Count)` approach and get a reference directly - should be more robust.

Comment: A simple way to insert images and keep them together with their captions is to insert both in-line into a table cell (you can apply text-wrapping to the table, if required). And, if you want to control the size of the inserted images, use tables cells having a fixed height and width. For some code demonstrating this appraoch, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/47919-post2.html